# GetElementsByClassName Unable to Get Class InnerText

Tags: excel, vba, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname, getelementsbyname

I can't figure out how to getelementsbyclassname.  I have the following Tag.  I can do getelementsbytagname by doing ("div") and listing its item number but I wanted to get to the class name item 2 in this instance.  On the webpage here is the tag.

```
<div class="column">

Projected Delivery Date:

</div>


<div class="column">

11/28/2017                                                                                                           
</div>
```

I am trying to get the date there.  This is code that I used to accomplish this. It isn't working with "partner_info group" nor "column".  I loop through all the tags and it doesn't seem to pick it up.

```
Private Function TrackNEW(trackingNumber As String) As String
Dim xml As Object
Dim tempString As String
Dim htmlDoc As Object  ' MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlBody As Object  ' MSHTML.htmlBody
Dim anchors As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim anchor As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim dda As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ddb As Object
Dim ddc As Object
Dim ddd As Object
Dim span As Object
Dim div As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set xml = GetMSXML
If xml Is Nothing Then  ' cannot start MSXML 6.0
TrackNEW = MSXML_ERROR
Exit Function
End If

tempString = GetResponse(xml, HTTP_GET, NEWUrl & trackingNumber, False)

If Len(tempString) = 0 Then

TrackNEW = ERROR_MSG
Exit Function
End If

Set htmlDoc = CreateHTMLDoc
If htmlDoc Is Nothing Then  ' cannot reference MSHTML object library
TrackNEW = MSHTML_ERROR
Exit Function
End If

Set htmlBody = htmlDoc.body
htmlBody.innerHtml = tempString
On Error Resume Next

Set dda = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
Set ddb = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
Set ddc = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
Set ddd = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("column")

For Each Strg4 In ddd
For ItemNumber4 = 1 To 600
Strg4 = ddd.Item(ItemNumber4).innerText
    If InStr(Strg4, "Projected Delivery Date:") >= 1 Then
    Strg4 = ddd.Item(ItemNumber4).innerText
    GoTo Line8
    Else
    End If
Next ItemNumber4
Next Strg4
MsgBox "Bad"
Exit Function
Line8:
TrackNEW = Strg4
Exit Function
```

If anyone can explain how to fix my code so it will pick up the date?  Again I could do getelementsbytagname for "div" but I want it by the class name if possible.  I am using VBA in Excel to do this.  This is not Java Script

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you can loop all the element with class of `column`. When you find the one with `Projected Delivery Date` as value then pick the item at the next index.
I use a CSS class selector to get a `nodeList` of all the matched elements and loop it.

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long
If htmlDoc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set nodeList =htmlDoc.querySelectorAll(".column")
For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    If InStr(nodeList.item(i).innerText, "Projected Delivery Date") > 0 Then
        Debug.Print nodeList.item(i + 1).innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I got this working and it reads the innerText of the elements with class="column", so see what you are doing differently and change it until you can get it to work.
Also you must add "Microsoft HTML Object Library" to the project under tools>references.

```
Sub sub1()
Dim hdoc As HTMLDocument

' your test HTML
sHtml = "<div class=""column"">" & vbCrLf & _
vbCrLf & _
"Projected Delivery Date:" & vbCrLf & _
vbCrLf & _
"</div>" & vbCrLf & _
vbCrLf & _
"<div class=""column"">" & vbCrLf & _
vbCrLf & _
"11/28/2017" & vbCrLf & _
"</div>"

Set hdoc = New HTMLDocument
hdoc.body.innerHTML = sHtml

For Each element In hdoc.getElementsByClassName("column")
    Debug.Print element.innerText
Next
End Sub
```